# Is there any way I can use drag & drop in Eclipse WTP Editors?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

It seems that Eclipse WTP doesn't support drag & drop Editing. I feel terrible when I write web pages. So how can I use drag & drop in Eclipse WTP Editors?

I mean select some text in the editor then drag & drop it into some other position.

Comment: No, I mean select some text in the editor then drag & drop it into some other position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For moving texts within your editor quickly you could use the alternative short-cut `alt+pageup` or `alt+pagedown`.

Comment: So this is not possible. In addition: the editor supports drop but no drag :) If you really really really need drag and drop, just open the file with the Java-Editor (right-click -> open with -> other...)